# Python - list comprehension as a decorator (including self)

Tags: python

I have two functions:

`job_status` is getting a response from boto3 api.

`jobs_details`is a list comprehension that performs `job_status` on each element of the input list.

I want to change `jobs_details` into a decorator of `jobs_status` but below solutions throws `inner() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given` error.

Appreciate any comment/alternative approach to my issue. Thanks!

```
import boto3

class GlueClient:

    def __init__(self):
        self.glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
        #self.envs = envs

    def jobs_list(self):
        response = self.glue_client.list_jobs()
        result = response["JobNames"]

        while "NextToken" in response:
            response = self.glue_client.list_jobs(NextToken=response["NextToken"])
            result.extend(response["JobNames"])

        return [e for e in result if "jobs_xyz" in e]


    #WHAT IS CURRENTLY
    def job_status(self, job_name):
         paginator = self.glue_client.get_paginator('get_job_runs')
         response = paginator.paginate(JobName=job_name)
         return response

    def jobs_details(self, jobs):
         return [self.job_status(e) for e in jobs]

    #WHAT IS EXPECTED
    def pass_by_list_comprehension(func):
        def inner(list_of_val):
            return [func(value) for value in list_of_val ]
        return inner

    @pass_by_list_comprehension
    def job_status(self, job_name):
        paginator = self.glue_client.get_paginator('get_job_runs')
        response = paginator.paginate(JobName=job_name)
        return response

glue_client = GlueClient()
jobs = glue_client.jobs_list()
jobs_status = glue_client.job_status(jobs)
print(jobs)
```

Comment: You point it out in your title—you're missing `self` in your definition. (Is there a reason to not simply write `job_status` such that it takes a variable number of arguments with `*`?)

Comment: A decorator is generally only useful if it will be used to modify different functions. If this is just for a specific function, there's not much point in it -- just put the code in that function.

Comment: I would need physical examples as I'm not sure how to combine both functions into one. Challenge is how to perform the comprehension inside `job_status`

Comment: you want something like `def inner(self, live_of_val): return [func(self, value) for value in list_of_val]` but I see no reason to do things this way. Why don't you just *define `job_status` to work this way*? It's very unexpected behavior

Comment: Also, `pass_by_list_comprehension` should not be a method, but just a function in the module. And `pass_by_list_comprehension` doesn't really make sense as a name...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want to do is make `job_status` iterate through a list of job names instead of operating on just one, something like this should work:

```
def jobs_status(self, job_names):
    paginator = self.glue_client.get_paginator('get_job_runs')
    return [paginator.paginate(JobName=job_name) for job_name in job_names]
```

Using a decorator to change what parameters a method expects seems like a bad idea.

Also, naming your class `GlueClient` would imply that it *is* a glue client. The fact that it *has* an attribute named `glue_client` makes me suspect you could probably choose a clearer name for one or both of them. (However, I'm not familiar with the package you're using.)

Comment: This is a pretty one-liner solution. I think that decorator would always be a good practice but in my scenario I agree it would be an overkill. Thanks for the other suggestions as well.

Comment: Good practice with decorators is to usually leave the function signature (that is, what parameters it takes) unchanged, unless you have a really good reason for doing otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

You want something like:

```
import boto3
from typing import Callable


def handle_iterable_input(func):
    def inner(self, list_of_val):
        return [func(self, value) for value in list_of_val]
    return inner

class GlueClient:

    def __init__(self):
        self.glue_client = boto3.client('glue')
        #self.envs = envs

    def jobs_list(self):
        response = self.glue_client.list_jobs()
        result = response["JobNames"]

        while "NextToken" in response:
            response = self.glue_client.list_jobs(NextToken=response["NextToken"])
            result.extend(response["JobNames"])

        return [e for e in result if "jobs_xyz" in e]

    @handle_iterable_input
    def job_status(self, job_name):
        paginator = self.glue_client.get_paginator('get_job_runs')
        response = paginator.paginate(JobName=job_name)
        return response

glue_client = GlueClient()
jobs = glue_client.jobs_list()
jobs_status = glue_client.job_status(jobs)
print(jobs)
```

This is the most basic way to make your decorator handle methods properly, by explicitly handling the passing of `self`. Note, it assumes the function being decorated will only take a single argument.

Comment: Did you mean to use `Callable` as a type hint for `func`, after you import it?